# Video files mysteriously deleted

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, delete

I get some files deleted when doing this, it happened twice and it doesn't happen anywhere else:

- I download some mp4 files with Chrome or Brave, both in incognito mode, and directly to the microSD card, as the internal storage is almost full
- for some reason, when choosing microSD as download folder, apps don't let you choose the folder, so they get downloaded to /Android/data/com.android.chrome/files/Download
- media players don't seem to find that folder, so I use [File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphainventor.filemanager&hl=en) move them to /DownloadsSD also on microSD storage
- I play them with MX Player, but at some random point they disappear (but other files that were in that folder before stay there, the only ones deleted are the newly downloaded ones)

The card is formatted as internal storage.
Do browsers delete files downloaded in incognito mode? Or maybe it has something to do with using the microSD card as internal storage?

Comment: [Related](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/180227/131553) - try solution there

Comment: @beeshyams How much could it take to rebuild the media index?

Comment: It didn't work then